# Can't get expected result with Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I also tried `[a-zA-Z]{2,}-\d+` but with the same results

```
def verify_commit_text(tags):
    for line in tags:
        if re.match('^NO-TIK',line):
            return True
        elif re.match('^NO-REVIEW', line):
            return True
        elif re.match('[a-zA-Z]-[0-9][0-9]', line):
            return True
        else:
            return False
if __name__ == '__main__':
    commit_text_verified = verify_commit_text(os.popen('hg tip --template "{desc}"'));
    #commit_text_verified = verify_commit_text(os.popen('hg log -r $1  --template "{desc}"'));
    if (commit_text_verified):
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print >> sys.stderr, ('[obey the rules!]')
        sys.exit(1);
```

if i use a text `"JIRA-1234"` the regex in :

```
 elif re.match('[a-zA-Z]-[0-9][0-9]', line):
```

does not seem to work and i get:

```
[obey the rules!]
```

on stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is working exactly as you've specified it .. it is searching for **1** character and **1** digit.  You probably want something like

```
re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]+-\d+\Z', line)
```

Further, always prefix regular expression strings with an 'r' as in the above.  Or it will bite you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to match one or more letters and numbers, you need to use the `+` like this:

```
r'[a-zA-Z]+-\d+'
```

You can also specify a certain number of letters (for example) with `{}`:

```
r'[a-zA-Z]{2,}-\d{4}'
```

Here, `{2,}` means 2 or more, `{4}` means exactly 4, `{,3}` means 0-3, and `{1,5}` means 1-5 inclusive.